# $.post always failed ASP.NET MVC with provider hosted app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365-apps, provider-hosted

I'm using following code in a SharePoint provider hosted MVC app to hit a controller method

```
var urlAddProduct = "/Home/AddProduct?SPHostUrl=" + spHostUrl;
$.post(urlAddProduct,
        {
          id: id            
        }).done(function () {

        }).fail(function () {
             alert("Failed to add the new product!");
 });
 //method
  [SharePointContextFilter]
 public ActionResult AddProduct(string id) {
    var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
    using(var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost()) {
    }
  return View();
}
```

Code is working fine but always return in failed state/failed alert.I am not getting any code exception.

Comment: Replace the `fail` function with `.fail(function(xhr, status, error) { /* check error */ });` and check the error it passes into the function.

Comment: error says "AddProduct its master was not found  no view engine supports . the following locations were searched...". I have a button inside index.cshtml and on button click ,i am running the code

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, check to see if you have a view in your solution under path `/Views/Home/AddProduct.cshtml`

Comment: I do not want to add a view ,it is a just button inside index.cshtml and click on button I want to call a Action method inside home controller.Isn't /Home/AddProduct try to call AddProduct action and it is calling though but with return as view error

Comment: So you want to call the action to perform some functionality, but you don't require any response about the result? Instead of `return View();` use `return new EmptyResult();`

Comment: Thanks ,got it ,this is working.But what If I want to use return view() with setting some data ViewData["abc"] ="text" and returning view() ,how can I avoid this error while using same index.cshtml view.SInce the button is on same view index.cshtml it is supposed to return view.Please correct me

Comment: Best way to do that is to return a JSON object using something like `return new JsonResult(new { abc = "abc"});` and handle the response on the client using Javascript/Jquery